# Cannot change a keyboard layout on the lock screen

Tags: keyboard-layout, lock-screen, input-language, capslock, gnome-screensaver

I have two keyboard layouts installed in my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS + GNOME. Sometimes, after some idle period, my computer goes into a *lock screen* when the layout is the other than I need to type my password. And there is no way to change the layout in this lock screen. I'm unable to input my password and unlock the computer.

The workaround is to go to the **Switch user** menu — in this case the layout become `en_US` again, and then I'm able to login. But is there any way to fix the bug?

How can I switch keyboard layout form a lock screen?

P.S. I use <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to change the layout.

---

The problem is probably related to [this yet unfixed bug 1244548](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/1244548) in `gnome-screensaver`.

Comment: Does default <Super+Space> work for you on the lockscreen?

Comment: `<Super + Space>` doesn't work in this situation. It just produces `<Space>` — or some other character that I cannot see — in the input field.

Comment: FYI, the default Ubuntu 18.04 lock screen *has* a way to switch keyboard layouts.